# Getting error when trying to run Sails.js on SQLite 3

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sails.js

I was trying to invoke Sails.js with SQLite 3, but it  throws  the following error.

[image: Error image]

Comment: Please add some code so we can try to help

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `waterline-sqlite3` package.
Try to run:

```
npm install --save waterline-sqlite3
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this same problem, i fix it by changing the connection configurations file under `config/connections.js` and i just put

```
sqlitedb: {
  adapter: 'sqlite3', // -> put this instead 'waterline-sqlite3'
  filename: './dev-db.sqlite',
  debug: false
}
```

That seem's to work, but im using knexJs to handle the migrations so i think something its not working fine with that because when i lift my app and go to postman to test it, only shows me

```
{
"code": "E_UNKNOWN",
"message": "Encountered an unexpected error",
"data": {
    "raw": {}
}
}
```

But i think, if your are not using `knexJs`, this will work for you.